# How To Lock Usb Ports on SQL/SBS Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to know how to lock the usb ports on my SQL Server 2008 R2.  Preferably only the usb ports on the front of the server. 
We have an audit coming up and apparently that’s on the list of things that need to be locked down...don't ask me I just comply :-)

As always thanks for any and all assistance in this matter,

David92595

P.S.  If you know how to do this on a SBS 2008 R2 system as well that would be an awesome bonus!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming and programmer's tools related questions, not operating system administration questions. Voting to close as off-topic and migrate to a more appropriate site. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of questions that are on-topic here.